# How to create my own Preference class

Tags: android

Can you please tell me how can I create my own Preference class in andorid? with my own layout and own click listener?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, that's about six or seven pages in a [book](http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid/), so it's a bit involved for a StackOverflow answer. :-)

[Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-colormixer) with a custom `View`, which is also wrapped into a custom `Preference`. It is only ~80 lines of code, though much of the UI smarts are bound up in the custom `View` class.

In a nutshell, to make a custom `DialogPreference`, you need to define:

- The constructors
- `onCreateDialogView()` and `onBindDialogView()` to create the dialog contents and populate the contents with the preference data
- `onDialogClosed()` to handle when the user changes the preference
- `onGetDefaultValue()` to handle your overall default if the preference is not yet set
- `onSetInitialValue()` to either load in the preference value or use your default

Comment: I create a class which sub-class DialogPreference, and overload onCreateDialogView and onBindDialogView(), but for some reason, when I run in debugger, these 2 methods never get called.

And I see blank as the preference when i debug in emulator.

Comment: @michael: it is difficult for me to advise you in the abstract. One option is for you to clone my code, get it working, then convert it into what you need step-by-step.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this sample is more understandable and is well depicted: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/seekbar_preference.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As well as the other two answers, I found it's also a good idea to look at the Android source code. For example, [CheckBoxPreference](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.java) and [DialogPreference](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/preference/DialogPreference.java#DialogPreference). Neither class is very big, so if you can get your head around how they work, you should be able to implement your own.